# Excel 2016 to DataGridView in Windows Forms Visual Studio 2019 community

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2019, excel-2016

i use Excel 2016 , Visual Studio 2019 community
and want to export the Excel sheet into a Data Grid View.
In addition I would like to select certain colums which will then be adopted.
The program is running to the fill function of the data set then the program is running to the catch without displaying an error message

```
    private void Cmd_Fbd_Data_List_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            OpenFileDialog openFileDialog1 = new OpenFileDialog();  //create openfileDialog Object
            openFileDialog1.Filter = "XML Files (*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb) |*.xml; *.xls; *.xlsx; *.xlsm; *.xlsb";//open file format define Excel Files(.xls)|*.xls| Excel Files(.xlsx)|*.xlsx| 
            openFileDialog1.FilterIndex = 3;



            openFileDialog1.Multiselect = false;        //not allow multiline selection at the file selection level
            openFileDialog1.Title = "Open Text File-R13";   //define the name of openfileDialog
            openFileDialog1.InitialDirectory = @"Desktop"; //define the initial directory




            if (openFileDialog1.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)        //executing when file open
            {

                string pathName = openFileDialog1.FileName;
                string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(openFileDialog1.FileName);
                DataTable tbContainer = new DataTable();
                string strConn = string.Empty;



                FileInfo file = new FileInfo(pathName);
                if (!file.Exists) { throw new Exception("Error, file doesn't exists!"); }
                string extension = file.Extension;



                switch (extension)
                {
                    case ".xls":
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                    case ".xlsx":

                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                    default:
                        strConn = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" + pathName + ";Extended Properties='Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1;'";
                        break;
                }

                String name = "DPL";// is the Name of the first Sheet


                OleDbConnection con = new OleDbConnection(strConn);

                OleDbCommand oconn = new OleDbCommand("Select * From [" + name + "$]", con);

                OleDbDataAdapter sda = new OleDbDataAdapter(oconn);

                DataTable data = new DataTable();
                // up to this line the programm works after that the Exception shows up
                sda.Fill(data);

                Dgv_Data_List.DataSource = data;


            }

        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Error!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please try to open the "OleDbConnection" `con.Open()`.

Comment: I did, but it still doesn't work. I implemented con. Open() directly after initializing con.

Comment: I do not understand what the problem is. The posted code appears to open an Excel file then fills the grid with data taken from the worksheet called “DPL”… It appears you are missing the “Exceptions” parameter to get the error message. To get the error “message” try changing the last catch statement to: `catch (Exception ex) { MessageBox.Show("Error: " + ex.Message); }`

Comment: i solved it with Closed XML and it worked out very well

Answer (score 0):

I was just checking the [MSDN documentation of OleDbDataAdapter.Fill](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.data.oledb.oledbdataadapter.fill?view=netframework-4.8) and it says there that it requires an ADODBRecordSet as second parameter. Is that not the case here? Check out the example in the documentation to see if that way instead of using an OleDbCommand maybe works for you.

Comment: Thanks for that info. Next question ist how to initialise this second Parameter.
What kind of object does the fill method need?

Comment: There is an example on the documentation, CTRL+F for "custDA.Fill" and you will find it. See how it's done there and try if that works for you.